# Blog post comment without page refresh (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to make comments on my page just like the ones in wordpress. When you press post comments your page updates without reload. How can I do that?

I understand I have to use jquery post, and I've had several attempts but for some reason my web page keeps reloading. I have a form like this :

```
<form name="postForm" id="postForm" action="addComments.php" method="post">
<textarea name="commentContent"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="commentButton" id="commentButton">
</form>
```

I tried `$("#commentButton").click(function()` do something .. but I still get the page reload. I mean I have the php part ready, working with page reload like an ordinary form just fine, just I'd like to learn and do this without page reload. Any idea how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/. It is jQuery plugin to submit form without page load... hope it will help you..

Comment: Is it compatible with latest jquery? If not it will save me some time :D tnx

Comment: it is compatible... I'm always using it... :))

Comment: Hmm I made progress but for some reason I get errors with firebug jQuery is not defined and $ is not defined, but it works ..

Comment: I don't know why you didn't get more vote up this is really gr8

Answer (score 3):

There is a great tutorial I found while i was searching something similar like adding, deleting comments without page refresh.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/insert-delete-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Answer (score 3):

You must `return false` from the click handler function to prevent default browser action – which is, submit the form. So your handler might look something like this:

```
$("#commentButton").click(function() {
    ...do your stuff...
    return false;
});
```

Or you can bind to the submit event also:

```
$("#postForm").submit(function() {
    ...do your stuff...
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#postForm').submit(function() ...

Comment: This will not reload the page if you return false - i thought this is common knowlede - my bad